# Oracle Apex - include user on execute immediate query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have the following query for an execute immediate:

```
begin

execute immediate q'['delete from MY_TABLE where USER_EMAIL = 
lower(v('APP_USER'))]';

end;
```

But I'm getting this error:
ora_sqlcode: 00900 Invalid SQL Statement

Anybody knows how can I include the user in there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's completely invalid statement, it isn't application user that makes it wrong.

Try

```
execute immediate q'[delete from MY_TABLE where USER_EMAIL = lower(v('APP_USER'))]';
```

or

```
execute immediate 'delete from my_table where user_email = ' || lower(:APP_USER);
```

---

On the other hand, why do you want to use dynamic SQL? There's nothing *dynamic* here, so ordinary

```
delete from my_table where user_email = lower(:APP_USER);
```

would do.